# How do I sync between RMD and ROS？

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

For example, I want to CURD in RMD, then sync to ROS.
When it's offline, I can get the data in RMD.
And how do I synchronize the entire RDM to ROS?
here is my code:
SearchModel

```
RealmUtils.getInstance()
            .where(Book.class).equalTo("isbn13", isbn)
            .findAllAsync().<Book>asObservable()
            .subscribe(books -> apiListener.onSuccess(books.size() > 0),
                    throwable -> apiListener.onFailure(throwable.getMessage()));
```

InsertModel

```
RealmUtils.getInstance().asObservable()
            .subscribe(realm ->
            {
                Book book = realm.createObject(Book.class);
                book.isbn13 = bookInfoResponse.getIsbn13();
                book.title = bookInfoResponse.getTitle();
                book.subtitle = bookInfoResponse.getSubtitle();
                book.publisher = bookInfoResponse.getPublisher();
                book.authors = bookInfoResponse.getAuthors();
                book.translators = bookInfoResponse.getTranslators();
                book.pubdate = bookInfoResponse.getPubdate();
                book.pages = bookInfoResponse.getPages();
                book.origin_title = bookInfoResponse.getOrigin_title();
                book.image = bookInfoResponse.getImages().getLarge();
                book.summary = bookInfoResponse.getSummary();
                book.infoString = bookInfoResponse.getInfoString();

                apiListener.onSuccess(true);
            }, throwable -> apiListener.onFailure(throwable.getMessage()));
```

DeleteModel

```
RealmUtils.getInstance()
            .where(Book.class).equalTo("isbn13", isbn)
            .findAllAsync().<Book>asObservable()
            .subscribe(books ->
            {
                books.deleteAllFromRealm();
                apiListener.onSuccess(false);
            }, throwable -> apiListener.onFailure(throwable.getMessage()));
```

and this will cause `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.`
so how can i do ?

Comment: synchronization is automatic if you have sync enabled and you use `SyncConfiguration`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So you mean I don't have to call the sync manually?

Comment: It'd be kinda crappy if you had to manage this yourself, no? :D realm already manages that stuff

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thx